# Solaris ethernet ports: nge2 and nge3 are missing

Tags: solaris, ethernet, port

There is a Sun X4100 with an interface `nge0` which is configured and working. The server has a group of 4 network jacks in the back and `nge0` corresponds to ethernet port 0.

I tried enabling ethernet port 3 with `ifconfig nge3 plumb` and I received the output

```
ifconfig: plumb: nge3: Invalid argument
```

But I am able to configure `nge1` no problem.

Here is the output of `prtconf -D`

```
i86pc (driver name: rootnex)
    scsi_vhci, instance #0 (driver name: scsi_vhci)
    isa, instance #0 (driver name: isa)
        asy, instance #0 (driver name: asy)
        motherboard
    pci, instance #0 (driver name: npe)
        pci10de,5e
        pci10de,cb84
        pci10de,cb84
        pci108e,cb84, instance #0 (driver name: ohci)
            device, instance #0 (driver name: usb_mid)
                keyboard, instance #0 (driver name: hid)
                mouse, instance #1 (driver name: hid)
        pci108e,cb84, instance #0 (driver name: ehci)
        pci-ide, instance #0 (driver name: pci-ide)
            ide (driver name: ata)
            ide (driver name: ata)
        pci10de,5c, instance #0 (driver name: pci_pci)
            display, instance #0 (driver name: vgatext)
        pci10de,cb84, instance #0 (driver name: nge)
        pci10de,5d (driver name: pcie_pci)
        pci10de,5d (driver name: pcie_pci)
        pci10de,5d (driver name: pcie_pci)
        pci10de,5d (driver name: pcie_pci)
        pci1022,1200
        pci1022,1201
        pci1022,1202
        pci1022,1203
        pci1022,1204
    pci, instance #1 (driver name: npe)
        pci10de,5e
        pci10de,cb84
        pci10de,cb84, instance #1 (driver name: nge)
        pci10de,5d (driver name: pcie_pci)
        pci10de,5d (driver name: pcie_pci)
        pci10de,5d (driver name: pcie_pci)
        pci10de,5d (driver name: pcie_pci)
        pci1022,7458, instance #1 (driver name: pci_pci)
        pci1022,7459
        pci1022,7458, instance #2 (driver name: pci_pci)
            pci8086,1011, instance #0 (driver name: e1000g)
            pci8086,1011, instance #1 (driver name: e1000g)
            pci1000,3060, instance #0 (driver name: mpt)
                sd, instance #0 (driver name: sd)
                sd, instance #2 (driver name: sd)
                sd, instance #3 (driver name: sd)
        pci1022,7459
    iscsi, instance #0 (driver name: iscsi)
    pseudo, instance #0 (driver name: pseudo)
    options, instance #0 (driver name: options)
    xsvc, instance #0 (driver name: xsvc)
    objmgr, instance #0 (driver name: objmgr)
    used-resources
    cpus
        cpu, instance #0
        cpu, instance #1
        cpu, instance #2
        cpu, instance #3
```

Any ideas on how to configure port 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your prtconf information you have 2 nge interfaces ( nge0 and nge1 ), and two e1000g interfaces ( e1000g0 and e1000g1 ).

Try to plumb them and they should work.

```
ifconfig e1000g0 plumb
ifconfig e1000g1 plumb
```

On a side note, if you have Solaris 10 it is easier to check for network interfaces with `dladm show-dev`